# Conditional update of multiple entries in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a relative newbie in mongodb but have lots of experience in MySQL.

I want to do a simple query that would appear in MySQL as follows:

```
UPDATE {database}.{table} SET {FIELD1}='{VALUE1}' WHERE {FIELD2} = {VALUE2};
```

e.g.

```
UPDATE test.user SET email='test@acc.ie' WHERE ref='12';
```

I don't want to destroy the database or collection on my first attempt.

I have only ever ran SELECT type queries on mongo, edited individual json entries or dropped an entire database.  A select in mongodb looks like the following

```
db.getCollection('user').find({email : "test@acc.ie"})
```

Is the following correct based on the MySQL example?

```
db.user.update({ref : "12"}, {$set: {email: test@ac.ie}}, { multi: true })
```

Because this is the response I am getting:

```
Updated 0 record(s) in 141ms
```

Comment: The syntax looks ok, you will get an error with how you are accessing the collection currently, change it to `db.user.update({ref : "12"}, {$set: {email: 'test@ac.ie'}}, { multi: true })` or `db.getCollection('user').update({ref : "12"}, {$set: {email: 'test@ac.ie'}}, { multi: true })`. Note, the value of the field being set should be quoted if it's a string. Best read the [**manual**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) for better referencing.

Comment: @chridam I removed the quotes around 12 and it worked for both your suggestions, doh!  Thank you!  Can you put in as an answer so I can resolve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks ok, you will get an error with how you are accessing the collection currently, change it to

```
db.user.update({ref: 12}, {$set: {email: 'test@ac.ie'}}, { multi: true })
```

or

```
db.getCollection('user').update({ref: 12}, {$set: {email: 'test@ac.ie'}}, { multi: true })
```

**Note**: the value of the field being set should be quoted if it's a string and unquote if a number. Best read the **[manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)** for better referencing.